# Call to a member function middleware() on null

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.4

I use the following middleware in routing Laravel:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'adminController')->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('profile', 'profileController')->middleware('role');
});
```

I get this error when i call 'admin' or 'profile' path in URL
[image]

Comment: Hi @ramzi, how did you add the middleware to resource, I mean what way did you find to add the middleware to resourse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `Route::resource()` does not return anything. Its void. It doesn't return an object.

[Laravel 5.4 - Illuminate\Routing\Router@resource](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L245)

In Laravel 5.5 (in development), `Route::resource()` will be returning an object for fluently adding options to.

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
Route::prefix("/dashboard")->middleware(['first','second'])->group(function(){
});
```

Comment: why does this work. Previously I had ```Route::prefix('app')->group(function() { //routes here})->middleware('auth');``` which did not work, but placing the middleware call before the group(function()) works.... but why? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply reverse the order:

```
 Route::middleware('scope:clock-in')->resource('clock', 'ClockController');
```

As lagbox stated:

> `Route::resource()` does not return anything.

However middleware does.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your resource controller is not resolving to an actual controller. Some things to check

- Check you actually have an adminController, and that the class name is in the correct case
- Check that your controller is in the default namespace and, if not, change the controller namespace, or add a namespace attribute to your route
- Check that your controller is not causing an exception on start that is being ignored resulting in you having a null controller.

Comment: i get this error just when i add " middleware('auth') "

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8.x you can solve this problem with:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth','middleware' => 'role'], function () {
  ..........
});
```